# HOW TO CHANGE SHAREPOINT DEFAULT DASHBOARD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, default

Hi I would like to ask if is it possible to change the default link of SharePoint link from office 365 to a specific site collection? I'm still new to SharePoint and I'm really having hard time working on this. thank you in advance. See Screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can add custom tiles to your App Launcher (if you have the correct permissions).

> In the Office 365 admin center, in the left navigation choose Settings > Organization profile > Add custom tiles for your organization.

[image]

References:

- [Add custom tiles to the My apps page and app launcher](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-custom-tiles-to-the-My-apps-page-and-app-launcher-1136115a-75af-4497-b693-640c4ce70bc6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)
- My own blog: [Add custom tile to Office 365 App Launcher](http://www.spnerd.com/home/addcustomtiletooffice365applauncher)